# Annual average humidity by country

Tags: weather, climate, meteorology

Is there any source that aggregates average humidity around the world by country? Ideally I'd want annual or five-year averages. NOAA seems like it might have something buried in its labyrinthine website, but I'd rather not deal with their 'check out' data request system when I want data for 100+ countries.